# How to create a brainwallet with bitcoinjs?

Tags: wallet, bitcoinjs, brain-wallet

This is how to create a brainwallet with bitcore

```
const Bitcore = require("bitcore-lib");
// const Mnemonic = require("bitcore-mnemonic");
// https://bitcore.io/api/lib/crypto
let brainsrc= 'satoshi'
let input = new Buffer(brainsrc)
let hash = Bitcore.crypto.Hash.sha256(input)
let bn = Bitcore.crypto.BN.fromBuffer(hash)
let pk = new Bitcore.PrivateKey(bn).toWIF()
let addy = new Bitcore.PrivateKey(bn).toAddress();
console.log('The brain wallet of '+brainsrc+' \nAddress: '+addy,' Private key:'+pk)
```

For bitcoinjs, I only know how to create random address:

```
// https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/v3.3.2/test/integration/addresses.js

const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom()
var secret = (keyPair.toWIF())
var addr = (keyPair.getAddress())

console.log('The brain wallet of '+brainsrc+' \nAddress: '+addr,' Private key:'+secret)
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use 1 word seeds, that will be too easy to brute force...

**index.js**

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')

const brainsrc = 'satoshi'
const hash = bitcoin.crypto.sha256(Buffer.from(brainsrc))
const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromPrivateKey(hash)
const addr = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey }).address
const secret = keyPair.toWIF()

console.log('The brain wallet of '+brainsrc+' \nAddress: '+addr,' Private key:'+secret)
```

**output:**

```
$ node index.js
The brain wallet of satoshi
Address: 1xm4vFerV3pSgvBFkyzLgT1Ew3HQYrS1V  Private key:L4XnHhvLC1b4ag9L2PM9kRicQxUoYT1Q36PQ21YtLNkrAdWZNos6
```

Examples can be found on the git repo: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib#examples

Comment: TypeError: bitcoin.ECPair.fromPrivateKey is not a function

Comment: what version of `bitcoinjs-lib` and `node` are you using?

Comment: Yes node. I upgraded to  4.0.0 and it works.

Comment: It would be a plus if you can provide a link to the documentation

Comment: Good idea, just edited the answer, Bitcoinjs-lib doesn't have formal docs, but there are examples.